# Is it possible to copy a Google Cloud Project from one organisation to another?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The idea is to replicate the project in a different organisation, with all the same options. Same api's, sql databases, and so on...

I looked at terraform. But I don't know if it is the best option.

Comment: The simple answer is no, you cannot clone a project with all settings, all data, all applications, databases, etc. Google supports exporting a project into Terraform format, but recreating the new project requires a lot of manual management/backup/restore and understanding of the difference between a project's configuration/settings and the applications/data of a project. https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/resource-management/export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a way to replicate a project as-is.

You can export your cloud resources to Terraform and then import them into your new project. Terraform is helpful in resource creation only but not the data.  You can refer to the following documentations For [exporting](https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/resource-management/export) and [importing](https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/resource-management/import).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am going to take a look at terraform.